# Structural Search and Replace with Groovy Script constraints

Tags: java, search, intellij-idea, groovy, structural-search

How can I search if a given method parameter that is an integer is greater or equal to a given value, in structural search and replace? or is this even possible?

For example: Say I have 100 usages of this method

```
public void sendString(String msg, int interfaceId){ //doing stuff... }
```

and I want to check if an fixed (none variable number) is passed into the interfaceId is greater or equal to a given number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can. Structural search is very powerful:

Test.groovy

```
class Test {
  def test() {
    String.format("%s",1)
    String.format("%s","x")
    String.format("%s",3)
    String.format("%s","x")
    String.format("%s",5)
  }
}
```

Search Structurally settings:

- Search Template: `String.format($str$,$val$)`
- File Type: `Groovy`

Edit Variables Dialog:

- `val` variable:

  - Text/regexp: `\d*`
- `Complete Match` variable:

  - Script constraints

    - Script text: `Integer.parseInt(val.getText()) > 1`

Result of search, matches found:

```
    String.format("%s",3)
    String.format("%s",5)
```

So it found all invocations of String.format with second argument greater than `1`. So you can tweak it to your case by editing the `Script Text` setting.